# Topic particle for the location of existence

Tags: grammar

I read it on a grammar website that the following sentence:

> あかりはカバンに本があります。

can be translated like this:

> Akari has a book in her bag.

And I was wondering if it was possible to include the word "bag" in the topic as well (by moving it before the は), changing this phrase to:

> あかりのカバンは本があります。

Why would I want to do that? To say something along the lines of:

> In Akari's bag, there's a book.

However, for some reason, I get the feeling this is not exactly correct (maybe because は cannot substitute に in this case). So, my second variant is this sentence:

> あかりのカバンに本があります。

It came out quite long a question, but, to summarize, are any of my Japanese sentences correct?

Comment: You could say には.  As in the joke にわにはにわにわがあります:　庭には鶏二羽があります。

Comment: @A.Ellett - 庭には二羽鶏（にわとり）がいます。

Comment: @aguijonazo Oops.  That makes more sense.  And, jeez I get いる and ある mixed up.  Perhaps because I was hungry when I wrote that, subconsciously, I was already thinking of the chickens post-mortem.  Excuses, excuses.

Comment: @A.Ellett - にわとり become とり when they die. Nice try, though.

Comment: @aguijonazo Interesting point, I did not know that.  Coolio.

Comment: @A.Ellett - Well, that was in the sense that cows become beef and pigs pork. No one sells chicken (meat) as にわとり although the kanji 鶏 remains unchanged. There was a TV show that asked silly commonsensical questions and it was titled トリニクって何の肉⁉︎ Presumably some people fail to make the connection.